# client side and server side validation asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, client

I'm working with Asp.net MVC4 for form validations.

I have done the client side validation with **JavaScript** and the server side validation with **model** and **Data Annotations**.

the problem is when I submit the form  for testing, I get client side validations errors messages (JavaScript) and the server side validations messages (Data annotations) at the same time.

Does any one know how can I forse the **Data Annotations** (server side) to work only when the **javaScript** is desactivated on client side?

Comment: If you enable unobtrustive javascript and client side validation, as well as including jquery val, the validation will be done on the client side as well by the data annotations.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation

Comment: Is the client side validation occurring *without* a form submit? The data annotation validation will only occur when the form is submitted to the server.

Comment: your javascript code?